# gnuplot, splot, xyz equal scale, graph too small

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to plot a 3D picture from data (below). All axis should have equal scale. However resulting picture is too small relative to canvas size.
How can I fill most canvas with the plot?

I tried changing canvas size, or setting size 1,1.

Data (5 squares):

```
0 0 0
1 0 0
1 0 1
0 0 1
0 0 0


0 0 0
1 0 0
1 1 0
0 1 0
0 0 0


0 0 0
0 1 0
0 1 1
0 0 1
0 0 0


0 0 0
-1 0 0
-1 0 1
0 0 1
0 0 0


0 0 0
-1 0 0
-1 1 0
0 1 0
0 0 0
```

I am using gnuplot 4.4 patchlevel 3,
commands:

```
set term pdfcairo size 2,1;
set xrange [-1.05:1.05];
set yrange [-0.05:1.05];
set zrange [-0.05:1.05];
unset key; unset border; unset tics;
set lmargin 0; set rmargin 0; set tmargin 0; set bmargin 0;
set view equal xyz;
set output 'address';
splot 'data.txt' w l;
unset output;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "set view" command contains two scale factors.  The first scale factor scaless the entire plot, the second one scale the z axis only.

```
 Syntax:
       set view <rot_x>{,{<rot_z>}{,{<scale>}{,<scale_z>}}}
```

The easiest way to adjust this is using an interactive terminal. Click and drag with the middle mouse button to adjust the scale factors to taste.  Then use `show view` to note the current values.  Add those to your script.  For example to scale the whole thing by a factor of two:

```
set view ,,2.0
```

Comment: Thank you! I kept scaling and changing range until the picture was large enough and on screen.